# Is there an embedded control that ensures that Windows updates are applied in proper sequence?

Tags: installation

I would like to know if there is a control technique that is embedded internally in the Windows update modules to ensure that EARLIER modules don't replace or overlay LATER modules?
For instance, is there a creation date in an update module that is being installed that would make sure that modules are installed in the correct sequence?  It might be possible, when I have a long list of a hundred updates to install, that I might release the ones on the end before I release the ones in the beginning of the list.
If there are two or more updates for the same code/module then it might end up with the earliest module in place once all the updates have been installed.
But if there is a date that would keep only the latest ones to be installed then it doesn't matter the sequence of installing a few at a time.
This has nothing to do with the question of installing what TYPE of modules first before other TYPES.
I know that there is discussions in this and other forums that touch on the sequence of module types, but this is about an internal date/time control.
Thank you for you consideration.
Roger.

Comment: Valid question. Even Google doesn't know the answer.

Comment: It is very hard to SEARCH that question - believe me, I tried to word it carefully several ways and all I got back was talking about the types of modules.  If I was writing the control program that installed the modules/code that are considered "updates" I would certainly make sure of some type of date-time control mechanism.   I have wandered about this question for many years.

Answer (score 0):

From WU's behavior we can deduce that it likely does dependency and date checking.

```
Start PC, no updates pending. 
Check for updates, 12 updates available.
Install, reboot, all succeed.
Check for updates, 2 updates available.
```

These would all be updates that were available for several days and yet they arent returned for the first query.